# Magento 2 Add Custom Column To Sales Order Grid from Sales Order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Want to save column data

> instore_order_number (present in both tables)
>
> from sales_order to sales_order_grid

Currntly I am able to save the instore_order_number from sales_order to sales_order_grid but facing issue in mapping i.e. when I am saving instore_order_number it is creating a new row with 0 id i.e. it is not mapping the sales_order with sales_order_grid

Code:
di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="joins" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="table" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</item>
                    <item name="origin_column" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="target_column" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="instore_order_number" xsi:type="string">sales_order.instore_order_number</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

sales_order_grid.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="instore_order_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">instore_order_number</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
```

Note: didn't made install schema as the attribute was present in both tables

Answer (score -1):

In di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="instore_order_number" xsi:type="string">sales_order.instore_order_number</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
</config>
```

In Package/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component under sales_order_grid.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="instore_order_number" class="Package\Module\Ui\Component\moduleGridColoumn\OrderNumber">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Instore order number</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">99</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
</listing>
```

In Package/Module/Ui/Component/moduleGridColoumn under OrderNumber.php

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Ui\Component\moduleGridColoumn;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory;
class OrderNumber extends Column {

/**
 *
 * @var Object 
 */
protected $_resource;

/**
 *
 * @var Object 
 */
protected $_scopeConfig;

/**
 *
 * @var Object 
 */
protected $escaper;

public function __construct(
ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, Escaper $escaper, array $components = [], array $data = []
) {
    $this->escaper = $escaper;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource = []) {
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (array_key_exists($this->getData('name'), $item)) {

                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $item['instore_order_number'];
            } else {

                $item[$this->getData('name')] = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
}
```